# Friend Request and Confirmation issue

Tags: python, django

so i currently have my likes app which deals with friend requests, and it works fine however my notification dont seem to be working. Whenever some likes someone else regardless of weather they are liked by that user or not it only sends the second of the two notify.send.

heres my code:

View.py

```
def like_user(request, id):
    pending_like = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    user_like, created = UserLike.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
    liked_user, like_user_created = UserLike.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if pending_like in user_like.liked_users.all():
        user_like.liked_users.remove(pending_like)
    elif request.user in liked_user.liked_users.all():
        user_like.liked_users.add(pending_like)
        notify.send(request.user, 
                        #action=request.user.profile, 
                    target=request.user.profile, 
                    recipient=pending_like,
                    verb='sent you a friend request view'),
    else:
        user_like.liked_users.add(pending_like)
        notify.send(request.user, 
                        #action=request.user.profile, 
                    target=request.user.profile, 
                    recipient=pending_like,
                    verb='accepted your friend request view')
    return redirect("profile", username=pending_like.username)
```

models.py

```
class UserLikeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_all_mutual_likes(self, user, number):
        try:
            qs = user.liker.liked_users.all().order_by("?")
        except:
            return []
        mutual_users = [][:number]
        for other_user in qs:
            try:
                if other_user.liker.get_mutual_like(user):
                    mutual_users.append(other_user)
            except:
                pass
        return mutual_users



class UserLike(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='liker')
    liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_users', blank=True)

    objects = UserLikeManager()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_mutual_like(self, user_b):
        i_like = False
        you_like = False
        if user_b in self.liked_users.all():
            i_like = True
        liked_user, created = UserLike.objects.get_or_create(user=user_b)
        if self.user in liked_user.liked_users.all():
            you_like = True 
        if you_like and i_like:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

as you can see in my views.py i have an if statement with one elif, however it never seems to pick up on that elif and goes direct to the else, so in my notifications i always get the 'accepted your friend request view' message. I cant seem to fix this issue if anyone can see an faults please let me know.

When i use it in my profile app to display a button showing, confirm friend request it seems to work. here is my code for the profile:

view.py

```
 def profile_view(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    liked_user, like_user_created = UserLike.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    do_they_like = False
    if request.user in liked_user.liked_users.all():
        do_they_like = True  
        context = {
            "do_they_like": do_they_like
                    }
        return render(request, "profiles/profile_view.html", context)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your below line

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
```

Update above with below line

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, however it doesn't seem to work, ive added a bit of code above showing an instance of when liked_user.liked_users.all(): seem to work.